# How to open Service Manager ticket using a protocol

Tags: scsm-2012

Is it possible to open a Service Manager ticket using a network protocol (like mailto: does for Outlook)? And what is the format?

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hh495588.aspx briefly shows the `msscnav:` protocol but I'm unable to find more information than:

> msscnav://root/Windows/Window/ConsoleDisplay/Folder.f837da16-dc5d-7a25-1b48-c62eb5965806/Folder.8afcc5db-910c-35a0-700f-fd9a94b4169b/View.fbf52403-7ce7-05c4-0ca9-7c61030e5f57

Thanks.

Comment: I'm curious what problem you're trying to solve here that isn't handled by the self-service portal or System Center Orchestrator.

Comment: It's a legacy system integration problem.

Comment: So you simply need any way to open a ticket, or you need it done via a URL-style web service call? I ask because there are PowerShell cmdlets for SCSM that can create tickets programmatically, as well as an SDK if you want to tap in via C#.